# Importing material-ui library in a css file

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to use @material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange in my css file. Is it possible to import this library to my css file? I want to use it something like as follows

```
import deepOrange from '@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange';
import deepPurple from '@material-ui/core/colors/deepPurple';

.OrangeAvatar {
   margin: 10;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: deepOrange[400]
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can import like this,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

```
@import '@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange';
@import '@material-ui/core/colors/deepPurple';

.OrangeAvatar {
   margin: 10;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: deepOrange[400]
}
```

It's not recommended to do imports though for performance. You can read [this post](https://csswizardry.com/2017/02/code-smells-in-css-revisited/#css-import) from Harry Roberts